# UINavigationController same color as ViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In Swift 4.0, I am trying to apply same color for UINavigationBar as my viewController color, in-short I want transparent Navigationbar, I tried all option but still not able to see same color to Navigationbar & viewController. (see attached picture)

```
self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = backGroundColor
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = backGroundColor
self.view.backgroundColor = backGroundColor
```

[image]

I am aware if I use

```
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
isTranslucent = false
```

it will make transparent background but than tableview list might visible in navigationbar when it scroll to top, which I don't want it.

Any other option is available? Where navigation bar should be transparent as well as tablview list should not be visible in navigatiobar when tableview scrolling to top.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set color in that manner which look like same as your desired color after applying some effect by `UINavigationBar`, you can achieve this by changing your `UINavigationBar` background color with new values which is calculated from your original color.

You can get that value using below link:
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/tparry/Miscellaneous/blob/master/UINavigationBar_UIColor_calculator.html

By doing this you can keep your `Translucent` property to true and achieve the same result which you want.